# How to call MVC Api controllers HttpResponseMessage Post action using javascript as client?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am calling this action of api from client. The client code also see below.

**API Action:**

```
public class StudentTestController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetLessonInfo(int request)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = null;

            result = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,StudentTest.GetLessonInfo(request));

            return result;
        }
    }
```

**JavaScript client script:**

```
function SendRequest() {

        var url = "http://localhost:1938/api/StudentTest/GetLessonInfo";

        var data1 = "request=293";

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data1,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#txtResponce').val(JSON.stringify(data.Data));
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var errorText = xhr.status + "\r\n" + status + "\r\n" + error;
                $('#txtResponce').val(errorText);
            }
        });
    }
```

When i am trying to call Action with the above snippet it will not calling the controller action. How to solve this?

Comment: What the API action returns? A JSON response?

Comment: have you looked at the console while trying to make the request? If you are using chrome pressing f12 would reveal the console window. From the console you can track down the error.

Answer (score 2):

Pavan.
Have you tried this instead:

```
var url = "/api/StudentTest/GetLessonInfo";
var data1 = "293";
```

Maybe "request=293" can be considered as a string and not the "int" expected as parameter.
And since the int parameter is not nullable, maybe it's giving you a Bad Request response.

Check with Fiddler what is being sent to the server.

Comment: Hi Thiago, I tried with that also and the controller action not in the working application that is in different application and also it was api controller action. so URL and Data i am posting are correct the above code is working when the Request was 'HttpGet' and return type was JSONResult other than 'HttpResponseMessage'. so please help me the Request was 'HttpPost' and the return type other than JSONResult. Thank you very much your response.